# Firebase sends a JWT token with 'kid' in header. How to verify JWT with 'kid' value in MongoDB Stitch?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm trying to use MongoDB Stitch Custom Authentication to verify a JWT generated from Firebase auth. I'm getting the following problem when connecting to MongoDB:

```
error: "crypto/rsa: verification error"
```

I used the public key generated using the method mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

and saved the key in Stitch Values and Secrets. Also, specified the audience app id in Stitch from firebase app

```
const stitchClient = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("stitch-app-id");
const credential = new CustomCredential("firebase_token");
stitchClient.auth.loginWithCredential(credential);
```

*Hi,
After having a chat with support team, I understand that JWT token headers contain 'kid' value which needs to be removed from headers for the code to work.*

*I've tried a JWT created without 'kid' for testing purpose and it does work. But the JWT is being generated from firebase and hence I can't change the headers, which is the reason for the above error. Is there a way for verifying the JWT with 'kid' in headers?*

Comment: Hi Dear! Tell me if you have any progress/news about this problem! This is same situation for me...